# How to solve $y'+6y(t)+9\int_0^t y(\tau)d\tau=1$, $\,y(0)=0$

Tags: laplace-transform, integral-equations

I want to solve this equation. It reminds me something about Laplace transform.

I am sure that I must use it order to solve this:

$$y'+6y(t)+9\int_0^t y(\tau)d\tau=1,\qquad y(0)=0$$

Comment: Hint: take the derivative of the entire thing, get rid of the integral and then use whatever method you like.

Comment: Hi @luigi. **Welcome to Math.SE!** You might like to know that we use [Mathjax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) here (e.g. `$\theta$` for $\theta$).

Answer (score 5):

Let
$$z(t)=\int_0^t y(\tau)d\tau$$
then the ODE becomes
$$z''+6z'+9z=1,\quad z'(0)=0$$
Notice that $z_p=\frac{1}{9}$ is a particular solution and for the homogenous solution the characteristic polynomial is $$r^2+6r+9=(r+3)^2$$
and $r=-3$ is the unique solution so 
$$z_h(t)=(at+b)e^{-3t}$$
is the solution for the homogenous equation, and finally the general solution is
$$z(t)=z_h(t)+z_p$$
The coefficients $a$ and $b$ are determined by $z(0)=0$ and $z'(0)=0$ and differentiate $z$ to find $y$.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the Laplace transform, it becomes really easy:

Your equation in function of s is:

$$sY(s)+6Y(s)+\frac{9}{s}Y(s)=\frac{1}{s}$$

I used:
The derivation property:  $\mathscr{L}\{y(t)'\}=sY(s)+y(0)$
The integral property: $\mathscr{L}\{\int_0^t{y(t)}\}=\frac{Y(s)}{s}$
The transformation: $\mathscr{L}\{1\}=\frac{1}{s}$

So, you obtain:
$$Y(s)=\frac{1}{s^2+6s+9}=\frac{1}{(s+3)^2}$$

Now you can immediately counter transform this function to obtain:

$$y(t)=te^{-3t}$$

Using the transformation: $\mathscr{L^{-1}}\{\frac{1}{(s+a)^2}\}=te^{-at}$
or applying the frequency delay property: $\mathscr{L}\{y(t)e^{-at}\}=Y(s+a)$

Answer (score 0):

Hint :

Differentiate the both side :-)